# Como nomear as chaves de um dicionário a partir de uma lista (array)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Se eu tenho um dicionário deste tipo:

```
dados = {"indice1": [1, 2, 3], "indice2": [4, 5, 6]}
```

e quiser nomear as suas chaves: indice1, indice2 com o seguinte array:

```
names= ['nome1', 'nome2']
```

Eu posso fazer isto?

```
dados.keys()=names
```

De tal forma que me retorne:

```
dados = {"nome1": [1, 2, 3], "nome2": [4, 5, 6]}
```

Se não for assim, qual seria a forma correta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há como garantir que as chaves chaves do seu dicionário seriam renomeadas corretamente! Dicionários em Python não suportam a ordenação de suas chaves!

O mais perto que você poderia chegar disso seria usando a classe `OrderedDict` do módulo `collections`, veja só:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dados = OrderedDict([("indice1",[1, 2, 3]),("indice2",[4, 5, 6])])
names = ['nome1', 'nome2']

novo = dict(zip(names, dados.values()))

print(novo)
```

Saída:

```
 {'nome1': [1, 2, 3], 'nome2': [4, 5, 6]}
```

Comment: Chaves não podem ser renomeadas. São imutáveis.

Comment: A partir de Python 3.7, a  [ordem de inserção em um dicionário é garantida](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values). Portanto em Python >= 3.7 sua resposta funcionaria com um dicionário comum também.

Comment: Muito obrigada Lacobus! Seus conhecimentos me ajudaram muito!!!

Answer (score 2):

Suponha que você tenha o seguinte:

```
dados = {"batata": [1, 2, 3], "abacaxi": [4, 5, 6]}
```

E então você faz isso:

```
names = ['macaco', 'gato']
dados.keys() = names
```

Qual desses seria o resultado?

```
dados = {"macaco": [1, 2, 3], "gato": [4, 5, 6]}
dados = {"gato": [1, 2, 3], "macaco": [4, 5, 6]}
```

A resposta é que nenhum. Desse jeito, não há como o python saber qual chave seria trocada por macaco e qual seria trocada por gato. Assim sendo, o que você vai ter que fazer é isso:

```
dados = {"indice1": [1, 2, 3], "indice2": [4, 5, 6]}
troca = {"indice1": "nome1", "indice2": "nome2"}
dados2 = {}
for k in dados:
    dados2[troca[k]] = dados[k]
```

O dicionário `troca` serve para dizer qual chave do `dados` será substituída por qual outra chave no `dados2`.

O `for` percorre cada chave `k` de `dados` e usa ela para acessar o valor correspondente (`dados[k]`) e o nome da nova chave (`troca[k]`) para com isso ir populando o dicionário `dados2`.